# Vibration does not stop after cancel

Tags: android, notifications

I'm attempting to set up a heads up notification that persists for 30 seconds and vibrates while it is showing. However when cancelling or letting the notification timeout the vibration does not stop the vibration on some devices.

It does not work on the Pixel 3 running Android 9.
It works using either the OnePlus 6 running Android 9 or the Pixel running Android 10 Beta.

I've tried using the same context for producing the NotificationManagerCompat when launching and cancelling the attempt.
I've tried cancelling all notifications related to my app instead of just the one I actually want to cancel.
I've tried launching a broadcast and starting a receiver which in turn cancels the notification.

This is the notification channel I am using:

```java
AudioAttributes audioAttr =
            new AudioAttributes.Builder().setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE)
                .build();

NotificationManager notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
      if (notificationManager != null) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("channelId",
            "channelName",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
     channel.setDescription("Channel description");
        channel.setVibrationPattern({0L, 2000L, 2000L});
channel.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE), audioAttr);
        channel.enableVibration(true);
        channel.setLockscreenVisibility(VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        channel.setShowBadge(false);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(ch);
```

This is the launched notification:

```java
      Notification incCall = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,
          "someChannelId").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.someDrawable)
          .setContentText("Some text")
          .setContentTitle("Some title")
          .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
          .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
          .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
          .setAutoCancel(true)
          .setFullScreenIntent(intent, true)
          .setTimeoutAfter(30 * 1000)
          .build();

      incCall.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;

 NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)
          .notify(”some id”, incCall);
```

This is how I attempt to cancel the notification:

```java
      NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).cancel("someChannelId");
```

I've also tried:

```java
      NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).cancelAll();
```

I expect that the phone should stop vibrating when the notification is hidden. But the vibration continues even though the notification is hidden when cancel is called.

Comment: channel.setVibrationPattern({0L, 2000L, 2000L}) this causes to vibrate long

Comment: I'm now using {0L, 1000L, 1000L}

Comment: better assign a short vibration

Comment: The shorter vibration had no effect on whether or not the vibration stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code written by google themselves the configuration of the channel and notification differed somewhat:

http://androidxref.com/8.1.0_r33/xref/packages/services/Telecomm/src/com/android/server/telecom/ui/IncomingCallNotifier.java

Removing the line:

```
incCall.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT
```

caused the vibrations to stop when the notification was hidden. It did however make it stop working on other models, such as the Pixel running Android 10 Beta. Because of this I adapted entirely to the solution used in the link. The notification was built as follows:

```
 Notification incCall = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,
      "id")
      .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
      .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
      .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.someDrawable)
      .setContentTitle("title")
      .setContentText("content")
      .setAutoCancel(true)
      .setOngoing(true)
      .setTimeoutAfter(30*1000)
      .setFullScreenIntent(intent, true)
      .build();
```

This notification channel was built as follows:

```
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("id",
        "name",
        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    channel.setDescription("Description");
    AudioAttributes audioAttributes =
        new AudioAttributes.Builder().setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE)
            .build();
    channel.setSound(aRingtoneUri, audioAttributes);
    channel.setLockscreenVisibility(VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
    channel.setShowBadge(false);
    channel.enableVibration(true);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
```

This solved the issue for me.